# Not able to Save data in physical file while using docker through Sitecore Powershell

Tags: docker, powershell

I'm new to PowerShell scripts and want to create items in Sitecore's Shared Data folder in a Json file and save the uploaded Json file in the App_Data directory's location. I tried using fullpath and relative path in the script, but it does not function and returns an error.

[image]

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with powershell variable **$SitecoreDataFolder** to retrieve path related to App_Data, as from looking into the issue it seems its not getting the path you are specifying. If it doesn't work then do post your script here.

Comment: Thanks Rinku, the suggested solution is working as anticipated.

Comment: Its great that it solves your problem..... :)

Answer (score 4):

A few things to keep in mind.

1. When working with Sitecore `Items` you will need the PowerShell drive to be either `master:`, `web:`, or `core:`. This is necessary to ensure that the SPE provider is in use for managing content through the Sitecore API. This is when the `ItemType` would be something like a template name.
2. When working with filesystem data you will need to ensure the drive selected is something like `C:`. As mentioned by Rinku the use of **$SitecoreDataFolder** is a way to ensure that the proper drive is provided.
3. `New-Item` for the filesystem provider and SPE provider behave differently.

In your example you should run the command like the following:

```
New-Item -Path $SitecoreDataFolder\test-folder -ItemType Directory
```

[image: Test Folder]

You can use the command `Receive-Item` as seen in the [docs](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/common/receive-file#examples) to upload files.